# Twice job results in sql server, last one is left in progress

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have the job **MP - Create CSV** which execute a package SSIS in sql server 2008, when I check for the job history I see the result at step 0, I expand and I have 2 results for the step 1.
Fist result have the icon for **Success** with the result :

> Message
>   Executed as user: companyname\sa. The step succeeded.

The second one have the step 1 also, but with the icon for **In Progress** with the result :

> Message
>   Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>   Version 10.50.4000.0 for 64-bit
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  11:50:00 PM
>   DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
>   Started:  11:50:00 PM
>   Finished: 11:50:26 PM
>   Elapsed:  26.645 seconds

My problem is I have a report to show all the job with their status not equal to 1 (success), my report do not work anymore because of this result "In progress".
Here is the sql I use to run my report :

```
SELECT *  from  msdb..sysjobhistory WHERE run_status != 1
```

My questions are why do I have 2 results for my step ? I think I should have only one. And what should I do when I have a job with a step status left "In progress" ?

For more information, my job is running daily and succeed every time, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the desired results :

```
select h.server as [Server],
    j.[name] as [Name],
    h.message as [Message],
    h.run_date as LastRunDate, 
    h.run_time as LastRunTime
from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h
    inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobs j on h.job_id = j.job_id
        where j.enabled = 1 -- only check for enabled jobs
        and h.instance_id in
        (select max(h.instance_id)
            from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h group by (h.job_id))
        and h.run_status != 1 
/*0 = Failed
1 = Succeeded
2 = Retry
3 = Canceled*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am seeing the same behavior on one of my jobs as well - I'm on SQL Server 2005.  The only thing I could find online was that Microsoft was going to fix this in future editions of SQL Server, but it looks like it still occurs given your experience.
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265568/log-file-viewer.  I am seeing this on one job only, and it's been happening over the past week (that's as much history on this job I can view).  The job runs a DTS package.  We have other jobs that run DTS packages that do not have this behavior.

Answer (score -2):

Check the advanced properties of the job step this is happening on.
Are "Output file:", "Log to table" and "Include step output in history" checked?
If so, uncheck them and see if this issue goes away.